# rails select tag, getting undefined method map for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In my deals_controller.rb i have the new action defined here

```
 class DealsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @deals = Deal.all
    end

    def show
        @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @vendors = Vendor.all
        # code for select tags on _form view
        @vendor_options = @vendors.map{|v| [v.name, v.id] }

        @items = Item.all
        @item_options = []
        @items.each do |item|
            @item_options << [item.name, item.id]
        end

        @deal = Deal.new
    end

    def create
        @items = Item.all
        @vendors = Vendor.all
        @deal = Deal.new(deal_params)
        if @deal.save
            redirect_to @deal
        else render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def deal_params
        params.require(:deal).permit(:item_id, :vendor_id, :price)
    end

end
```

Then, inside my new.html.erb i have

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :vendor_id %><br>
    <%= select_tag(:vendor_id, options_for_select(@vendor_options)) %>
  </p>
```

When I try to create a new deal the program errors with

```
NoMethodError in Deals#create
Showing /Users/andrewkim/wdi/work/app/small_time_grocer/app/views/deals/_form.html.erb where line #21 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

The extracted source is from line 21 below:

```
 <%= select_tag(:vendor_id, options_for_select(@vendor_options)) %>
```

I don't even see where map is being used, or is that inherently being used in the options_for_select method?

The documentation on the select tag is a little cryptic to me, can anyone spot my error?

Comment: `@vendor_options = @vendors.map { |v| [v.name, v.id] }`

Comment: tried that before, gives me the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `collection_select` instead of `select_tag`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :vendor_id, @vendors, :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Please Select'}, {class: 'selectpicker chosen-select'} %>
```

I recommend to read about [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Any ideas why mine didn't work for the create functionality but worked for the view itself?

Comment: If you want to use `select_tag`, you don't need to use `map` ... simply you can use as `select_tag 'vendor_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@vendors, :id, :name, @deal.vendors.try(:id)), {prompt: 'Please Select', class: 'selectpicker chosen-select'}`

Comment: Why is this the solution? Does `collection_select` handle nil better or something?